# Proper datetime attribute for <time>

Tags: html, datetime, schema.org, microdata

While [Schema.org writes](http://schema.org/openingHours)

> Here is an example: `<time itemprop="openingHours" datetime="Tu,Th 16:00-20:00">Tuesdays and Thursdays 4-8pm</time>`.

on the [HTML5 validator](http://validator.w3.org/) I get this error:

> Bad value `Mo, Tu, We, Th, Fr 09:00-16:00` for attribute `datetime` on
>   element `time`: The literal did not satisfy the time-datetime format.
>
> ```html
> …" datetime="Mo, Tu, We, Th, Fr 09:00-16:00">every work day 9am to 16pm </time></li>
> ```

I really want to communicate the opening hours (and days) in Microdata, but it seems this is in conflict with HTML5.

Is there a format that is good for both or I should keep it for the bots and care not about valid HTML in this case?

Comment: possible duplicate of [schema.org openinghours](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8152854/schema-org-openinghours)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to keep what you have and not worry about the HTML validator which is only a guide at any rate.

Comment: Hmm, I actually meant to add this as a comment and not an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Don’t use the `time` element.

It’s an error with Schema.org’s documentation. I reported this [issue in the Schema.org tracker](https://github.com/schemaorg/schemaorg/issues/143) and it will likely be fixed in the next release.

Possible [alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26159198/1591669):

- [`data` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/text-level-semantics.html#the-data-element):

  ```html
  <data itemprop="openingHours" value="Tu,Th 16:00-20:00">Tuesdays and Thursdays 4-8pm</data>
  ```
- [`meta` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/document-metadata.html#the-meta-element) (which [can be used in the `body`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22415563/1591669)):

  ```html
  <meta itemprop="openingHours" content="Tu,Th 16:00-20:00"> Tuesdays and Thursdays 4-8pm
  ```