# Schema.org opening hours with lunch break

Tags: html, schema.org, microdata

My office is available Mon-Fri from 8-12, and then 1-5. In other words, we have a one hour lunch break where the office is closed.

How can I express this with Schema.org?

Am I allowed to have two time stamps in the same code like this?

```html
<time itemprop="openingHours" datetime="Mo,Tu,We,Th,Fr 08:00-12:00 13:00-17:00">Monday through Friday, 8 a.m. to noon</time>
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using [`openingHours`](http://schema.org/openingHours) (which seems to be somewhat underspecified), you might want to use [`openingHoursSpecification`](http://schema.org/openingHoursSpecification).

This allows you to use (in your case, multiple) [`OpeningHoursSpecification`](http://schema.org/OpeningHoursSpecification) values.

(Side note: using the `time` element for `openingHours` [is not valid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28089509/1591669).)