# How to link hours element to days element for Schema.org's "openingHours" in Microdata?

Tags: html, markup, schema.org, microdata

I am currently doing the markup for a website. I have got to the `openingHours`.

The problem I ran into is that the days and hours are in different elements.

How should one go about marking it up and linking the day of the week to the hours that are corresponding?

The code is as follows:

```html
<h2>Hours</h2>
<div id="hours">
<ul>
   <li>Mon-Wed</li>
   <li>Thursday</li>
   <li>Friday</li>
   <li>Saturday</li>
   <li>Sunday</li>
</ul>
<ul>
   <li>9:00 AM - 6:00 PM</li>
   <li>9:00 AM - 8:00 PM</li>
   <li>9:00 AM - 6:00 PM</li>
   <li>10:00 AM - 4:00 PM</li>
   <li>Closed</span></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the explanation from http://Schema.org/openingHours:

- Days are specified using the following two-letter combinations: Mo, Tu, We, Th, Fr, Sa, Su.
- Times are specified using 24:00 time. For example, 3pm is specified as 15:00.

Schema.org examples:

```
<time itemprop="openingHours" datetime="Tu,Th 16:00-20:00">Tuesdays and Thursdays 4-8pm</time>.
```

If a business is open 7 days a week, then it can be specified as:

```
<time itemprop="openingHours" datetime="Mo-Su">Monday through Sunday, all day</time>.
```

Remember that meta tags can be used for hidden data, while it isn't generally a great idea an exception would be for providing machine-readable dates if needed.

I would suggest something similar to this, so you can keep your layout the same:

```
<li><time itemprop="openingHours" datetime="Mo,We 09:00-18:00">Mon-Wed</time></li>
<li><time itemprop="openingHours" datetime="Th 09:00-20:00">Thursday</time></li>
<li><time itemprop="openingHours" datetime="Fr 09:00-18:00">Friday</time></li>
```

The lines containing times alone don't need markup because it's provided higher up, and Closed periods are not part of `openingHours` and can be left out.

Comment: Note that it’s [not valid to use the `time` element for this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28089509/1591669).

Comment: do you have a reference for that? Schema.org shows an example using the `<time>` tag, although I normally just use `<span>` myself

Comment: My [linked answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28089509/1591669) contains a reference: "I reported this [issue in the Schema.org tracker](https://github.com/schemaorg/schemaorg/issues/143) […]"

Comment: thanks,  I had missed that. I thought the example seemed... odd

Answer (score 0):

Using an `ul` element for this purpose is not correct (and it’s not accessible).

If you want to relate the days with the corresponding times, you could:

- use a `table`
- use a `dl`
- use text, i.e., day and time next to each other (with elements for styling)

If your markup/content doesn’t allow to provide the content in a form which you need for Microdata, you could always use the `meta` element (which is [allowed in the `body`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22415563/1591669) if used for Microdata).

But you might want to [consider using `openingHoursSpecification` instead of `openingHours`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30850786/1591669). It allows to markup [`dayOfWeek`](http://schema.org/dayOfWeek) and [`opens`](http://schema.org/opens)/[`closes`](http://schema.org/closes) separately.